# Masstransit, saga resource not being created

Tags: masstransit

I have two services, one acts as a consumer, the other as a producer. Following are my configurations for each of them.

Producer config

```
services
    .AddSingleton(KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);

services
    .AddMassTransit(config =>
    {
        config.AddBus(serviceProvider =>
            Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                config.Host(new Uri("amqp://admin:pass@localhost"));
            }));
    })
    .AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Consumer config

```
services
    .AddSingleton(KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);

services
    .AddMassTransit(config =>
    {
        config.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderStateMachine, OrderState>()
            .RedisRepository();

        config.AddBus(serviceProvider =>
            Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                config.Host(new Uri("amqp://admin:pass@localhost"));
                config.ReceiveEndpoint("service-5-queue", endpointConfig =>
                {
                    endpointConfig.Consumer<SubmitOrderCommand>();
                });
            }));
    })
    .AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Following some online tutorial, when the app launches, then I should see some queues and exchanges being created, one of which should be some 'order-state' exchange and queue. Unfortunatly not the case.

Anyone using masstransit having some idea why is this the case ?

The logs

```
[15:56:15 DBG] Declare queue: name: service-5-queue, durable, consumer-count: 0 message-count: 0
[15:56:15 DBG] Declare exchange: name: service-5-queue, type: fanout, durable
[15:56:15 DBG] Declare exchange: name: Messages:ISubmitOrder, type: fanout, durable
[15:56:15 DBG] Bind queue: source: service-5-queue, destination: service-5-queue
[15:56:15 DBG] Bind exchange: source: Messages:ISubmitOrder, destination: service-5-queue
[15:56:15 DBG] Consumer Ok: rabbitmq://localhost/service-5-queue - amq.ctag-X4WuaeOFDCCMcdEXd4EtuA
[15:56:15 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://localhost/service-5-queue
[15:56:15 INF] Bus started: rabbitmq://localhost/
```

Sending some message triggers the `consumer`, but the saga doesn't get trigger at any moment, nor it is invoked during some initialization steps or something.

```
[16:00:08 DBG] Declare exchange: name: Messages:IOrderSubmitted, type: fanout, durable [16:00:08 DBG] SEND rabbitmq://localhost/Messages:IOrderSubmitted 0cb00000-2327-309c-67c9-08d8ef964ca6 Messages.IOrderSubmitted 
[16:00:09 DBG] Create send transport: rabbitmq://localhost/DESKTOPNH4IRSD_Service1_bus_b1ayyybdrhajaxmebdcq9fqbrz?temporary=true 
[16:00:09 DBG] Declare exchange: name: DESKTOPNH4IRSD_Service1_bus_b1ayyybdrhajaxmebdcq9fqbrz, type: fanout, auto-delete
[16:00:09 DBG] SEND rabbitmq://localhost/DESKTOPNH4IRSD_Service1_bus_b1ayyybdrhajaxmebdcq9fqbrz?temporary=true 0cb00000-2327-309c-b0bc-08d8ef964d91 Messages.IOrderPreSubmissionOk [16:00:10 DBG] RECEIVE rabbitmq://localhost/service-5-queue 0cb00000-2327-309c-4f1f-08d8ef9647eb Messages.ISubmitOrder Service5.Handlers.SubmitOrderCommand(00:00:09.6961272)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the explicit receive endpoint configuration, and call `ConfigureEndpoints`. This will create the endpoint for the saga.

```csharp
services
    .AddMassTransit(config =>
    {
        config.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderStateMachine, OrderState>()
            .RedisRepository();

        config.UsingRabbitMq((context,cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(new Uri("amqp://admin:pass@localhost"));

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
    })
    .AddMassTransitHostedService();
```